# SORTC always moves first element of array to the end

Tags: arrays, sorting, sas

I've got a character variable which holds a delimited list of strings, like so:

```
data lists;

format list_val $75.;
list_val = "PDC; QRS; OLN; ABC";
run;
```

I need to alphabetize the elements of each list (so the desired result when applied to the above string is `"ABC; OLN; PDC; QRS;"`).

I adapted the solution [here](https://communities.sas.com/t5/General-SAS-Programming/Rearranging-a-Character-Strings-Into-alphabetical-order/m-p/394727#M49752) for my purposes as follows:

```
data lists_sorted;

set lists;

array_size = count(list_val,";") + 1; /* Cannot be used as array length must be specified at creation */

array t(50) $ 8 _TEMPORARY_;

call missing(of t(*));

do _n_=1 to array_size;

t(_n_)=scan(list_val,_n_,";");

end;

call sortc(of t(*));

new_list_val =catx("; ", of t(*));

put "original: " list_val " new: " new_list_val;
run;
```

When I run this code I get the following output:

`original: PDC; QRS; OLN; ABC  new: ABC; OLN; QRS; PDC`

Which was not expected or desired. In general, the result of the above code applied to any list is a new list which is sorted alphabetically, except that the first element of the original list becomes the last element of the new list, regardless of its alphabetical ordering.

I can't find anything in the documentation of [sortc](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n00aheqlqf6qdln1og24z2hcsfd6.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) which would explain this behavior, so I'm wondering if the issue is somehow the way I've set up the temporary array (I don't have much experience with these).

Does anyone know why sortc behaves this way? Side question: is there anyway I can dynamically determine the size of the array, rather than hard-coding a value such as 50?

Comment: DATA Step does not have dynamic arrays, array sizes are set at compilation time.  There are two mechanisms for accessible dynamic storage in DATA Step.1 - Hash object, 2 - Dynamic Function Array (DFA) package by Bartosz Jablonski (https://github.com/yabwon/SAS_PACKAGES) that surfaces the utility of FCMP based dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you included the leading spaces when assigning the values to the array elements.  Remove those.

```
t[_n_]=left(scan(list_val,_n_,";"));
```

If you want to know what the minimum size array you could use for your data step you would need to process the dataset twice.

```
proc sql ;
  select max(count(list_val,";") + 1) into :max_size trimmed from have;
quit;
....
array t[&max_size] $ 8 _temporary_;
```

But there is probably not much harm in just using some large constant value.

Comment: As usual, a wonderful and helpful answer. It seems so obvious now I feel foolish I didn't see it, but thanks for helping me to